# How to impliment this code on Wordpress site

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I was wondering how i can implement this code on a Wordpress site, as when i add it nothing seems to happen, the code is implemented on [this page](http://footballnewsdaily.net/arsenal/) :

```
<script>
    var links = $$(".feed-item a");
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        links[i].onclick = function () {
            location.href = "/mypage.html";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: do you insert that code in <script></script> tag?

Comment: I've added the code but nothing seems to have changed

Comment: can you post your file? In which file are you adding this code

Comment: [link](http://footballnewsdaily.net/arsenal/)

Comment: use code from @iamalismith's answer, your script code is broken, and variable name is bad. also, we can't see `links` declaration in your example.

Comment: Hi the code is changed look at the original post I've edited it

Comment: replace $$ with $. i suggest you to use console on your browser, to check for javascript errors.

Answer (score 1):

Put it inside `<script></script>` tags to tell the browser to interpret it as Javascript.

You can't have a hyphen `-` in a variable name, you could use camel case instead: `var feedItem`;

Also you have a missing `}` to close the for loop.

Altogether it would look like this:

```
<script>
    var feedItem;
    for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
        links[i].onclick = function() {
            location.href="/mypage.html"
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi I have changed it to what you put, but it still didn't work and i think the hyphen is necessary as it's trying to change items with the class feed-Item, however i tried it without and it still didn't work, the page is [link](http://footballnewsdaily.net/arsenal/)

Comment: Hi the code is changed look at the original post I've edited it